# identifying clustered element from a html page using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I want to identify the following element but unable to do so.

```html
<fieldset class="ng-scope" ng-if="permissions.isEditable &amp;&amp; (permissions.isApprover || permissions.isReviewer)">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
      <div class="label-container">
        <label>Reviewer comments <a class="tooltip-item" href="javascript:void(0);">[?]
                                <div class="tooltip">
                                    <p>Contents of the comment
                                        can be viewed by Immigration
                                        team and employee who logged
                                        the request.</p>
                                </div>
                        </a>
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="value-container">
        <textarea name="Comments" class="required-on-send-back required-on-hold required-on-reject ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="requisitionRequest.request.reviewerComments" rows="4"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Note there are 3 fieldset above as well .

Comment: what do you mean by the word clustered elements? and also post the html code for reference.

Comment: i mean after so many fieldset this one is there.

Comment: I want to identify the following element but unable to do so 
<fieldset class="ng-scope" ng-if="permissions.isEditable &amp;&amp; (permissions.isApprover || permissions.isReviewer)">

     
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="value-container">
                        <textarea name="Comments" class="required-on-send-back required-on-hold required-on-reject ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="requisitionRequest.request.reviewerComments" rows="4">                            </textarea>

Answer (score 0):

You can write a css selector based on the `fieldset` attributes like:

```
fieldset[ng-if*='isApprover'][ng-if*='isReviewer'][ng-if*='isEditable']
```

You can remove any of the [] condition block.

This xpath should help in identifying the fieldset:

```
//fieldset[.//textarea[@name='Comments']]
```